# phpmyadmin: Update a row in all entries in one time

Tags: php, mysql

How can I update a row in all database entries? So I don't have to write for example 30 times a code to update each entry.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM packages WHERE id = id");
$row = $query->fetch_object();

$number_now = $row->number-50;

$update_sale = $db->query("UPDATE packages SET number_now = '$number_now' WHERE id = id");
```

### [image: Heading]

Comment: you mean in all entries of table? in that case remove Where case.

Comment: Your above code is correct? you have both `number` and `number_row` in filed lists? If it is correct, to obtain `number_row = number-50` write this unique query: `UPDATE packages SET number_now = number - 50`

Comment: Not working. Then each entry in the row has the same value, for example 50. But the entries have a various number.

Comment: @fusion3k This was my mistake, but doesn't work again.

Comment: can show your table structure, please?

Comment: So from you initial `SELECT` query you're going to be left with x number of records that you need updating?

Comment: @fusion3k Embed a picture

Comment: @Marcus Yes thats it

Comment: SET number_row= number_row - 50 is that what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try this

$update_sale = $db->query("UPDATE packages SET number_now = number_now-50");